# Convert Plain Language Duration to Joda Period or ISO 8601

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a String that looks something like this: "n YEARS n MONTHS n WEEKS n DAYS" (note that the constants may or may not be pluralized)

I need to convert this to either a Joda Period object or an ISO 8601 formatted String (which can in turn be converted to a Period object).

Does anyone have any code, or can they point me to a library to do this?

**Update**: In case anyone needs to do this, here is the working code. Unfortunately, I had to dynamically build the PeriodFormatterBuilder since the fields were optional. A bit ugly, but it works.

**Update2**: Fixed error pointed out in comments.

```
String text = expr1a.getText();
System.out.println(text);

PeriodFormatterBuilder pfb = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().printZeroAlways();

int yearIndex = text.indexOf("YEAR");
int monthIndex = text.indexOf("MONTH");
int weekIndex = text.indexOf("WEEK");
int dayIndex = text.indexOf("DAY");

if (yearIndex > -1) {
  pfb = pfb.appendYears().appendSuffix(" YEAR"," YEARS");
}

if (monthIndex > -1) {
  if (yearIndex > -1) {
    pfb = pfb.appendPrefix(" ").appendMonths().appendSuffix(" MONTH", " MONTHS");
  } else {
    pfb = pfb.appendMonths().appendSuffix(" MONTH", " MONTHS");
  }
} 

if (weekIndex > -1) {
  if (yearIndex > -1 || monthIndex > -1) {
    pfb = pfb.appendPrefix(" ").appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" WEEK", " WEEKS");
  } else {
    pfb = pfb.appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" WEEK", " WEEKS");
  }
}

if (dayIndex > -1) {
  if (yearIndex > -1 || monthIndex > -1 || weekIndex > -1) {
     pfb = pfb.appendPrefix(" ").appendDays().appendSuffix(" DAY"," DAYS");
  } else {
    pfb = pfb.appendDays().appendSuffix(" DAY"," DAYS");
  }
}

PeriodFormatter pf = pfb.toFormatter();

Period period = Period.parse(text, pf);
return period;
```

Comment: You need to parse the string and extract the values, then it should be fairly simple to create a Joda duration from them. Take a look at some of the lexer implementations for java, http://www.giocc.com/writing-a-lexer-in-java-1-7-using-regex-named-capturing-groups.html for example.

Comment: In case there is not a `YEAR` value, then the formatter will have an extra space prefixing the month value, which will lead to a failure when parsing `4 MONTHS`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [PeriodFormatterBuilder](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html) of the joda time API to construct an instance, which parses your format. There is also handling for [plurals](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html#appendSuffix%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) of the constants.

Comment: One question though (which I should have made clear originally, and the javadoc isn't really clear). Can any of the "sections" (i.e. "n MONTHS") be optional when constructing the PeriodFormatter?

Comment: @Jason I'm not sure about that too. You could probably write some unit tests that cover these cases. In this way you would have also documented this feature for your co workers.